# How To Launch WinGDB GUI Outside of Visual Studio?

Tags: wingdb

If I look at the installation directory I see:

```
mhoggan@1USDMHOGGAN /cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/SoftErg/WinGDB
$ ls -l
total 19620
drwxrwx---+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM        0 Jan 26 11:00 1033
drwxrwx---+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM        0 Jan 26 11:00 Generators
-rwxr-x---+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM   583168 Jan 10 13:51 softergCrashReporter.exe
-rwxr-x---+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM    59392 Jan 10 13:52 softergProcessBreaker64.exe
-rwxr-x---+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM   546816 Jan 10 13:51 softergShell.exe
drwxrwx---+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM        0 Jan 26 11:00 Templates
drwxrwx---+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM        0 Jan 26 11:00 Visualizers
-rwxr-x---+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM  3116544 Jan 10 13:29 wingdb.chm
-rwxr-x---+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM  1363456 Jan 10 13:46 wingdbAdaLanguagePack.dll
-rwxr-x---+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM    30208 Jan 10 13:53 wingdbAutomationAPI.dll
-rwxr-x---+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM 11030016 Jan 10 13:50 wingdbEngine.dll
-rwxr-x---+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM  1495040 Jan 10 13:54 wingdbMakefilePack.dll
-rwxr-x---+ 1 SYSTEM SYSTEM  1845760 Jan 10 13:51 wingdbRemoteTerminalPack.dll
```

If I go to the start menu and type WinGDB I don't see any executable. However, http://www.wingdb.com/docs/pages/wg_launching.htm instructs me to use the UI I don't know how to launch. How do you launch WinGDB GUI from start menu or command line?

Comment: You're on the right track.  Q: What does softergShell.exe do?  Q: If you paid your $89.00, can you call or e-mail WinGDB support?

Comment: @paulsm4 It opens a cmd temporarily then closes, no gui launches.